# Cannnot handle the passed array in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my constructor

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            images: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
```

This how i am getting my images object

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
        let keyword = this.state.search;
        let GIPHY_KEY = 'xxx';
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({images:await fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${keyword}&api_key=${GIPHY_KEY}&limit=21`).then (response => response.json())})
        //console.log(this.state.images);
    }
```

Passing the images to child constructor; as below

```
<Result images={this.state.images.data}/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWT2o.png)

So when i am using javascript function such as length or forEach i am getting error as cannot read property 'length' or 'forEach'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
How to handle array in such situations

Comment: How do you use `length` and `forEach`? Please add that code.

Comment: Do not do `this.setState({ images: await fetch(...) })`, instead store the response from the `fetch` call in a variable like so `const data = await fetch(..)`, then do `this.setState({ images: data.images })`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the default value of `images` which is a string. Instead of this:

```
this.state = {
  search: '',
  images: ''
}
```

You need to set the default value of `images.data` to an `array` so that array functions will work

```
this.state = {
  search: '',
  images: { data: [] }
}
```

Comment: Actually images is a json object returned by fetch and it contains data which is an array

Comment: @SanketManmode don't use a string as the default for a property called `images` - it's misleading and why you're running into issues. Use an empty array, then when you call `fetch` and get your response, `JSON.parse(YOUR_RESPONSE)`, then grab the array you're interested in, and update your state with that array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got it. I think in child component first is should check if ths images.data is null or not. This seems to be the issue.

```
function result(images){
    if(images.data !=null)
    {
        console.log(images.data.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: This still fails because initially `this.state.images` is a string, so your `images.data != null` will cause another error at some point because it's not an option, which is what `images.data` assumes it is.

Comment: I initialized images images:{}, which seems to work

Comment: Yeah it probably works, but it is still misleading as I suggested, when I read the word `images` to me it implies it's an array, not an `object` or a `string`.